# Execute a script if we are at the beginning of the year quart

Tags: php, date, if-statement, strtotime

First I want to mention that, I have read the other's topics, and this is not a duplicate, as you will see from what I am asking below:

Earlier I asked a different question here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682432/how-to-proceed-through-all-cases-if-they-are-true-php/25682856?noredirect=1#comment40139630_25682856`

Now, I have realized, that the third case, this one:

```
$date = strtotime("1 October 2014");
if ( ((date('n') % 3) == '1') && (date('d') == '01') ){ 
      echo 'quarterly<br>';   
    }
```

It is not good for what I am looking for.
I need a script to trigger when the date has passed a quart's year and is at the first day of the first month from the quart? In other words, the script must trigger quarterly.

Any ideas??

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
((date('n') % 3) == 1)
```

Use:

```
(((date('n')+2) % 3) == 0)
```

Eg 1, January = month 1. 1+2 = 3. 3 Modulus 3 = 1, therefore TRUE

Eg 2, July = month 7. 7+2 = 9. 9 Modulus 3 = 1, therefore TRUE

Comment: 3 mod 3 is zero, same with 9 mod 3

Comment: My bad, edited.
However, this also means the original method should work fine. Looks like the real error is found below.

Comment: However it also means that the original code is fine :) (ie, if month is january, `date('n') % 3` does `== 1`)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem,seems like i forgot to add a parameter here:

```
    $date = strtotime("1 October 2014");
if ( ((date('n',$date) % 3) == '1') && (date('d',$date) == '01') ){ 
      echo 'quarterly<br>';   
    }
```

Of course it couldnt work,as long as it doesnt have any data parameter to format.Sorry guys,i must be more careful with my codes next time.

Comment: If you skip that parameter PHP assumes you mean the current date/time.